# How to access JPA Repository methods from bean object of the particular repository dynamically

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, reflection

I have a list of repositories that extends JPA Repository and the API needs to fetch a record of a particular table given a primary key..

I have defined a enum from where I'm able to fetch the repository class object from the given table name..

```
public enum DynamicEntityRepository {

    Table1(Entity1.class),
    Table2(Entity2.class),
    Table3(Entity3.class),
    Table4(Entity4.class),
   
    Class entity;

}
```

Now, I want to access the findById(id) method of JPA Repository of the particular table..

```
 DynamicEntityRepository repo = DynamicEntityRepository.valueOf(tableName);
 

 /*
   Here I want to access findById(id) of the particular repository by passing the param
*/
```

I have tried using reflection to invoke the findById method of the Repository class but it throws NoSuchMethodException as the Repository originally does not have findById method.. It indeed extends JPARepository's default method..

Is there any other way to solve this ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current solution is that JPA repositories need to be auto-configured by Spring Boot Data JPA to work.

**Solution**

You can use Spring to generate a map of all JPA repositories as proper autowired objects. Then in your code you can get the repository by the key. Which is the repository class name (without package).

Check the below example code which logs all defined repositories and their size using `findAll()`.

```
@Autowired
Map<String, JpaRepository> jpaRepositories;
// ...
for (Map.Entry<String, JpaRepository> repos : jpaRepositories.entrySet()) {
    List items = repos.getValue().findAll();
    log.info("repository: {}; size: {}", repos.getKey(), items.size());
}

Sample output:
repository: customerRepository; size: 1234
repository: phoneRepository; size: 117
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just have one clarification thoough as I'm pretty new to java spring..
How will you initialise the map here ?
jpaRepositories.put("table1", new Repository1()) will throw compile error as the repositories are interface and we cannot create instance..

Comment: The above code is all you need. Spring Boot will autowire the map. The only thing is that the class where you use it must be a bean managed by Spring. For example annotated with Component or Service.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This actually loaded all the repository classes into the map